# Saving tables and database created from Flask Sql Alchemy to ensure data persistence across sessions

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I just created a Flask application. I am trying to do some database operations. My init class of the app is

```
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


def __get_app() -> Flask:
    return Flask(__name__)


def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = __get_app()
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from .routes import api
        app.register_blueprint(api)
        db.create_all()
        db.session.commit()

    print("FLASK APP")

    return app
```

and one of the models is

```
"""Data models."""
from app import db
import json

class User(db.Model):
    """Data model for user accounts."""

    __tablename__ = 'flasksqlalchemy-tutorial-users'
    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True
    )
    username = db.Column(
        db.String(64),
        index=False,
        unique=True,
        nullable=False
    )
    email = db.Column(
        db.String(80),
        index=True,
        unique=True,
        nullable=False
    )
    website = db.Column(
        db.String(120),
        index=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
    password = db.Column(
        db.String(20),
        index=False,
        unique=False,
        nullable=False
    )
```

I'm able to create a database and the required tables using the above. The issue that I'm facing is how to save the database and table. I need some guidance on that.

I want to save the database on my local machine.

Update: Further context

I initially don't have a database. After the db.create_all(), I can query to the db and all the relevant tables are created. I want to save that db on the machine hosting the app. I cannot find the db anywhere too and it disappears as soon as I stop the application. Basically, persistence is not maintained between sessions

Comment: So you want to get a copy of the database which is on another machine, is that right?

Comment: No, it's not. I initially don't have a database. After the db.create_all(), I can query to the db and all the relevant tables are created. I want to save that db on the machine hosting the app. I cannot find the db anywhere too and it disappears as soon as I stop the application. Basically, persistence is not maintained between sessions.

Comment: You need to set the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` configuration option with the path to the database file (assuming that you are using sqlite).  [Example](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application)

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for sharing that. It looks promising. I'm just having trouble fixing the URI. I'm trying app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = """jdbc:sqlite:/Users/code/src/flask_project/app/flask_db"""

Getting sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '/Users/code/src/flask_project/app/flask_db'

Comment: Oh wow! it actually worked. I was missing sqlite:///. Like the three slashes. Thanks a ton @snakecharmerb